# Prepare Windows Server 2012 for web site hosting only

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2012-r2, web-hosting, website

Hi there I am a good programmer and also a complete newbie in windows administration so apologies for my fist question in serverfault. So I've just got a new server machine that I'm planning to host my company website on. I've created a vm with Windows Server 2012 and I've installed IIS and the site is up and running. The question is if I am going to use that vm just for hosting that single website what do I need to disable/enable just to make sure that no other services are open and listening for some sort of other connections (thus exposing the vm for more attacks)? Or are there any tools to scan the IP address for any known vulnerabilities? Everything that the website needs to function properly is already installed on the same VM and it does not need to connect to any "remote" machines (sql server is installed on the same VM). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable everything you don't need. If you have a running service, figure out what it is and whether you need it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes that is the question. How do I know what do I need  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things I would recommend disabling are 'Client for Microsoft Networks' and 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks'.
To get to those, go to the Network and Sharing Center, click on Change adapter settings, and then right click the network card(s) and select Properties.

Just untick the network services you don't need.

There may be plenty of other things to look at, but this will certainly reduce the exposed footprint of the machine.